# Внедрение интересного шрифта в тег title

Tags: html, css, веб-дизайн

На сайте https://aida.co.ua замечена интересная особенность - в теги title и description внедрено слово , выполненное неизвестным шрифтом, которое однако сохраняет свое форматирование, несмотря на то, что в тегах title и description не может быть использовано стилевое оформление.

При этом данное слово очень эффектно выделяется в списке сайтов поисковых систем.

Каким чудесным образом можно было этого достичь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это символы из UTF-8, блок "Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols"(U+1D400..U+1D7FF) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols

Answer (score 2):

Тут дело не в шрифте, а в Unicode символах
Например,  тут - это [Mathematical Bold Capital A](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1D400)

Comment: Спасибо, увы, первым ответил vrv